# Dynamic content in angular service workers.

Tags: angular6, progressive-web-apps

I am using service workers in Angular 6 application for the purpose of progressive web apps. I am able to store the staic content and images in Servcie workers. 
Any idea on how to store the dynamic content from API’s request in service workers.

Answer (score 0):

That code will do the trick. As far as your storage permits, you can addup all the contents into the service worker and can view them in cache storage in Application tab.

```
.then(response => {

  return caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
    cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
    return response;
  });
});
```